# Non- Local operators and Entanglement

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, interactions, locality

Given a separable state, $|\psi\rangle$ = $|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle$, operating on this state with a local operator of the form, $A\otimes B$ will not lead to an entangled state. Is the converse true? i.e., given that I know that action of an operator on a separable state is a separable state, can I conclude that the operator must've been a local operator?

or will the action of a non-local operator always entangle a separable state?

Comment: The "or" in the last sentence does not seem to make sense logically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The swap operator will never entangle any product state, yet it is not a local operator.

(Note, however, that it will create entanglement if it acts on *part* of a larger system.)